# Java- Non-zero Int Divide by 10 is Equal to 0.0 in Float?

Tags: java, android, floating-point

I have a volume control slider to control the volume of a audio file playback in Android.

```
vSlider=(SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seekBar2);
        vSlider.setMax(10);
        if(mediaPlayer.isPlaying()){
            isPlaying=true;
            try {
                currentPosition = mediaPlayer
                        .getCurrentPosition();
                double seconds=currentPosition/1000;
                int time= (int) Math.round(seconds);
                String timeS=Integer.toString(time);
                timer.setText(timeS+"s");
                Log.d("position",timeS);
                fSlider.setProgress(currentPosition);
            }  catch (Exception e) {

            }
            vSlider.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener(){

                @Override
                public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                        boolean fromUser) {
                    float volume=progress/10;
                    Log.d("Progress", String.valueOf(progress));
                    Log.d("Volume",String.valueOf(volume));
                    mediaPlayer.setVolume(volume, volume);

                }
                @Override
                public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }
                @Override
                public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { }                        
            });
```

The int value of the slider progress is being detected correctly, but the float volume always becomes 0.0. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `progress/10` is an integer division. Try `progress/10f` instead. You possibly have another similar issue if `currentPosition` is an int.

Comment: progress/10 is an integer division, which yields 0 if progress is less than 10. Afterwords it is converted to a float 0.0. You need to perform a float division: volume = ((float) progress) / 10.0;

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
float volume=progress/10;
```

Operation on two `int` gives result as `int`. So cast the result as

```
float volume=(float)progress/10;
```

or

```
float volume=progress/10.0f;
```

See [casting hierarchy](http://staff.science.uva.nl/~heck/JAVAcourse/ch4/ss1_1.html#ArithmeticOperators) there are explicit and implicit cast

Comment: (float) is not required. But otherwise correct. Fix this and I'll +1.

Comment: @aquestion That won't work , `10.0` is a `double` literal.

Comment: @The New Idiot: are you sure about this? 10 is an int literal. 10.0 is a double literal which will cause progress to be promoted to a double. I agree though that 10.0f is better.

Comment: @Bathsheba Sorry for the typo , i meant `10.0` will result in compilation error.

Comment: @The New Idiot: but I compiled with no error, Eclipse

Comment: @aquestion It should be a compilation error , unless `volume` is `double` or you use a cast `(double)` in front of the expression.

Comment: @The New Idiot. Wow I didn't know that. Is that a Java 'standard'? I agree though that the answer should have 10.0f though just do stop unnecessary promotions and implicit casts.

Comment: @Bathsheba A compile-time error on assignment of a double expression to a float variable is indeed required by the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/conversions.html#184206).

Answer (score 1):

Use a `float` literal `10.0f` to force a floating point arithmetic.

```
float volume=progress/10.0f;
```

By default the *R.H.S* of the below code is an integer airthmetic expression :

```
float volume=progress/10;
```

Since `progress` is an `int` and `10` is an `int` literal. Since it performs an *integer division* , if `progress` is lesser than `10` , the expression will evaluate to `0` and `volume` will be `0.0`.

Answer (score 1):

In the line

```
float volume=progress/10;
```

**first** you're doing the *integer* division `progress/10` and getting an integer result (and so if `progress` is anything `< 10`, you'll get `0`), and then you're just casting that result to a `float`.

You want a floating-point division instead:

```
float volume=(float)progress/10;
```

There, we're first atking `progress` and making it a `float`, *then* doing the division and saving the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
float volume=progress/10.0;
```

do it as above to get right answer. Int divide by int will always be a integer you are just assigining a integer 0 to float , by which result will be 0.0

Answer (score 0):

That is because of type conversion:

When you do any `int/int` --Output is in-> `int` which is then assigned to float

So if you want output in float

`float/int` or `int/float` --Output is in--> `float`

Keeping that in mind:

```
float value = progress/10.0f //as by default 10.0 is double in java
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because you are making an integer division and then cast the result to a float. Try this instead:

```
float volume = progress / 10.0f;
```